# Como puedo retornar un array con la sumatoria del contenido de otro array? Usando las propiedades de los Array

Tags: javascript, array, bucles

Muy buenas tardes companeros, como estan?

Una consulta, tengo un array en javascript con los siguientes valores [0,1,2,3,4,5]

Como puedo hacer para que me devuelva el siguiente array [0,1,3,6,10,15] utilizando las propiedades del mismo array?

Se me ocurre que quizas con un reduce() pero no logro hacer que me devuelva un array, solo me devuelve un valor.

Muchisimas gracias por su apoyo,
Saludos

Comment: Ese único valor puede ser un array

Answer (score 1):

Podrias hacer un doble bucle facilmente, pero si queres usar un metodo podes usar un forEach:

```
let arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
let res = [];

arr.forEach((index) => {
  let aux = 0;
  for(let i=0;i<index+1;i++)
    aux += arr[i];
  res.push(aux)
})

console.log(res);
```

Seguro podes usar reduce pero no la tengo muy clara con ese metodo.

Comment: Para eso es mejor usar forEach, map devuelve algo que está siendo ignorado

Comment: tenes razon, ahi lo cambie.

Answer (score 1):

De hecho lo puedes hacer con un `reduce`. Algo como:

```js
const progressiveSum = (numbers) => numbers.reduce(
  (acc, cur, index) => [
    ...acc,
    (acc[index - 1] || 0) + cur,
  ], [],
);

console.log(progressiveSum([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Usando reduce:

```js
const a = [ 0,1,2,3,4,5,6];

function sumar(acumulado, item) {
  
  if (acumulado.length) {
    acumulado.push(item + acumulado[acumulado.length -1]);
  } else {
    acumulado.push(item);
  }
  return acumulado;
}

console.log(a.reduce(sumar,[]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Con `for` y `push()` podrías hacerlo:

```js
let arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5];

let result = [];
let suma = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  suma += arr[i];
  result.push(suma);
}

console.log(result);
```